# How can I permanently change the class of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, video

I am trying to make the seek bar of a video site clickable and controllable by getting rid of the read-only css class but I have to manually get rid of it for every video. Is there any way to permanently get rid of it or to somehow automatically get rid of it every time the page refreshes?

I tried manually getting rid of it and that worked but it is quite tedious.

```
<div id="seek" data-tabindex="0" tabindex="0" class="progress-bar read-only" style="position:  absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: visible; transform-origin: center center; width: 169px; height: 30px; transform: translate(44px, 18px); display: block;">
      <style>
        #seek:before {
          border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          background-image: initial;
          background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        }
      </style>
```

Comment: Write a browser extension that does `document.getElementById("seek").classList.remove("read-only")`

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do it, but one way to do that would be through JS like this.

```
const readOnlys = document.querySelectorAll('.read-only')

for (let i = 0; i < readOnlys.length; i++) {
    readOnlys[i].classList.remove('read-only').
}
```

If you run this code, it selects all elements with the `read-only` class and then removes it from those elements.